# AlertDialog's title without ellipsize

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, title

Hello I have a simple AlertDialog with that title: *Are you sure you want to send to previous location these x items?*

But the result looks like this[image: AlertDialog title with ellipses]

So I thought if I set this TextView to null the problem may be solved.

But the result was this[image: AlertDialog title without ellipses]

Do you have any idea how can I show the whole text on the AlertDialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it by setting the single line property of the TextView to false!